# How to check completed orders when user is logged in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I create a shop and I use ASP Identity razor pages to login, logout and registration. I have default IdentityUser. I have also ASPNetUsers table and I want reference row UserId to my other table Orders. My main purpose to achieve is when user logg in, he can check his completed orders from database. I know how to use LINQ to get order from database, but I didn't know how to connect that with Identity. I also use Session for adding item to cart if it is important.

```
 public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubGenre> SubGenres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShipAddress> ShipAddresses  { get; set; }
}

 public class ShipAddress
    {
        [BindNever]
        public int ShipAddressId { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz swoje imię!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Imię:")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz swoje nazwisko!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Nazwisko:")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz nazwę ulicy!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Ulica:")]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz numer domu/lokalu!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Nr domu/lokalu:")]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz kod pocztowy!")]
        [StringLength(6)]
        [Display(Name = "Kod pocztowy:")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz miejscowość!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Miejscowość:")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wpisz numer kontaktowy!")]
        [StringLength(9)]
        [Display(Name = "Nr telefonu:")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [BindNever]
        public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }

        [BindNever]
        public DateTime OrderPlaced { get; set; }

        public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
        public int IdentityUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Current Login User**

```
 var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

This will give your current login user id then you can apply linq for based on this id with and condition of completed order you store in table

Comment: Ok but I need store identity user Id in table Order. What should I write to my Order entity to reference ASPNet Users table? If  I will have that I can compare a currently log user Id with user Id in order table. Then I will get concrete order.

Comment: please share that code do you have any field that can identify the bill is completed or not

Comment: Ok done. Now when i create migration and update database I get error  "The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.

Comment: I don't tell you to add an identity in you database I tell you to add column like iscompleted so that you can put where clause on that and get completed document --what are fields in orders that can show that order is complete

Comment: KonradDybkowski  - you have to use both userId in and the flag for complete so that you can match both in where clause to get no of order full fill by that particular user

Answer (score 1):

Use User's Identity which u logged in by using
string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: Hahaha yes im so stupid ! I just do that like you write before i read your post. 

I create a string property UserId in ShippAddress class and then in controller i just write shipAddress.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(User);

Comment: what I have answered same